# convert constant in python to user defined

Tags: python, constants

I have a constant file in python where i have defined below constant

UNI_PER_ONT=1

Suppose I have 5 ONTs (ONT1, ONT2...) like below having the mentioned number of UNI_PER_ONT

```
ONT1 - 3
ONT2 - 6
ONT3 - 10
ONT4 - 60
ONT5 - 1
```

I dont want UNI_PER_ONT to be same for all the ONTs. If i define 1 value for it, it will take the same value for all the ONTs.
I want that each ONT can have different value for UNI_PER_ONT

Note: you can consider ONT also as a variable

Comment: It is a little unclear what you want. Maybe you can say a bit more about what your usecase is?

Comment: I want the user who is running the application to tell me what value he wants for UNI_PER_ONT instead of doing Constants.UNI_PER_ONT as it will always take value as 1.

Answer (score 2):

it is not a constant, it is variable. You can allow users set the value in different ways:

- use interactive input method

> ```
> UNI_PER_ONT = input('please enter UNI_PER_ONT value')
> ```

- console argument (using argparse lib)
- environment variable

> ```
> import os
> os.environ.get('UNI_PER_ONT')
> ```

Comment: I have modified the question for better understanding